# Prove that $b^x=\sup\{b^t\mid t\in\mathbb{Q}\wedge t\leq x\}=\lim_{n\to\infty}b^{p_n}$ when $p_n\to x$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, continuity

Let $b>1,x\in\mathbb{R}$.
Let's suppose we define
$$R_x=\{b^t\mid t\in\mathbb{Q}\wedge t\leq x\}.$$
and then $b^x=\sup R_x$.

Let now $\{p_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be an arbitrary sequence such that $p_n\to x$.

---

I want to prove that $b^{p_n}\to b^x$.

I don't want to use $\epsilon/\delta $... so I thought about this.

Let $\{p_{n_k}\}$ a strictly increasing subsequence, so $p_{n_k}\to x$ and $\sup\{p_{n_k}\}=x$. I now want to prove that $\sup\{b^{p_{n_k}}\}=\sup R_x$, as $b^x$ is increasing as defined.

How could I do that?

If the sequence $p_{n_k}$ was of rational then $b^{p_{n_k}}$ would be in $R_x$ and that would be $x\leq \sup R_x$, but I cannot assume that.

Note: I cannot use continuity of $b^x$ (In fact i want to use this, to show the sequential continuity of $b^x$ and then the continuity)

Comment: This is exercise 7 of Chapter 1 of Rudin's _Principles of Mathematical Analysis_. He broke this problem into several steps, try to follow the steps there.

Comment: You should use the fact that $f \, : \,\, x \mapsto b^x, \,\,  x \in \mathbb{Q}$ is strictly increasing.

Comment: @Solitary, I know that part, and from that exercise we can define $b^x=\sup R_x$.
What I want, is to prove that if $p_n\to x$ then $b^{p_n}\to b^x$, as sequences.

corindo, so I should use that fact further. I'll try looking into it.

Comment: @LeviathanTheEsper If you have access to this problem in Rudin's book, I will post an answer, using the notation therein. Also my answer refers to parts (a) - (d). Note logically, you don't need limit (or continuity) concept to prove this (because this exercise appeared in Chapter 1 and limit came after that in Chapter 3).

Comment: @Solitary Yes, now that I see it, I was thinking about the exercice 6. But I still don't see why is it related, what I want to prove (This is my question) is that for every sequence $p_n$ which converges to $x$, $b^{p_n}$ converges to $b^x$, with the definition from the exercise 6 in mind.